# Could someone explain to me about the training Tesseract OCR?

Tags: windows-8, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to do the training process, but I don't understand even how to start. I would like to train for read it numbers. My images are from real world, so it didn't go so good with the reading process.

It says that I have to have a ".tif" image with the examples... is a single image of every number (in this case) or a image with a lot of different types of number (same font, though)?

And what about the makebox? The command didn't work here.

https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3

Could someone explain me better, at least how to start?

I saw a few softwares that do this more quickly, but I tryied one (SunnyPage 1.8) but isn't free. Anyone know any free software that does this? Or a good tutorial?

Using Tesseract 3, Windows 8 (32bits).

Answer (score 3):

It is important to patiently follow the training wiki google code project site. If needed multiple times. It is an open source library and is constantly evolving.

You will have to create a training image(tiff) with a lot of different types of numbers probably should have all the numbers you wish the engine to recognize.

Please consider posting the exact error message you got with make box.

I think Tesseract is the best free solution available. You have to keep working and seek help from community.

There is a very good post from Cédric [here](http://www.cedricve.me/2013/04/12/how-to-train-tesseract/) explaining the training process for Tesseract.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: Thanks, it would be great if your answer could quote or sum up the main parts of Cédric's post, in case the link goes down. ([see guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer))

Comment: link is now definitely down :(

Answer (score 0):

A good free OCR software is PDF OCR X which is also based on Tesseract. I tried to copy my notes from German which I had scanned at 1200dpi, and the results were commendable but not perfect. I found that this website - http://onlineocr.net - is a lot more accurate. If you are not registered, it allows a maximum of 4mb file size from most image formats (BMP, PNG, JPEG etc.) and PDF. It can output them as a Word file, an Excel file or an txt file. 
Hope this helps.